# Ruby Gems install error on GitLab (cannot find -lmagic_ext)

Tags: ruby, gcc, rubygems, puppet, gitlab

I am attempting to install GitLab which is failing at a step where it is attempting to install charlock_holmes, the following is the error output I receive...

I am installing this through Puppet however it seems to be that it cannot find the library lmagic_ext on the final make in the process of building charlock_holmes from source.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

```
Error: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/gem install -v 0.6.9.4 --no-rdoc --no-ri charlock_holmes' returned 1: ERROR:  Error ins                                          talling charlock_holmes:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -licui18n... yes
checking for main() in -licui18n... yes
checking for unicode/ucnv.h... yes
  -- tar zxvf file-5.08.tar.gz
  -- ./configure --prefix=/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/dst/ --disable-shared --enable-stat                                          ic --with-pic
  -- patch -p0 < ../file-soft-check.patch
  -- make -C src install
  -- make -C magic install
checking for main() in -lmagic_ext... yes
checking for magic.h... yes
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
gcc -I.  -I/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/dst/include -I. -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux                                           -I. -DHAVE_UNICODE_UCNV_H -DHAVE_MAGIC_H    -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ss                                          p-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fno-strict-aliasing  -fPIC  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c encoding_detector.c
common.h:14: warning: 'charlock_new_enc_str' defined but not used
gcc -I.  -I/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/dst/include -I. -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux                                           -I. -DHAVE_UNICODE_UCNV_H -DHAVE_MAGIC_H    -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ss                                          p-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fno-strict-aliasing  -fPIC  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c converter.c
common.h:23: warning: 'charlock_new_str' defined but not used
common.h:32: warning: 'charlock_new_str2' defined but not used
gcc -I.  -I/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/dst/include -I. -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux                                           -I. -DHAVE_UNICODE_UCNV_H -DHAVE_MAGIC_H    -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ss                                          p-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fno-strict-aliasing  -fPIC  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c ext.c
common.h:14: warning: 'charlock_new_enc_str' defined but not used
common.h:23: warning: 'charlock_new_str' defined but not used
common.h:32: warning: 'charlock_new_str2' defined but not used
g++ -I.  -I/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/dst/include -I. -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux                                           -I. -DHAVE_UNICODE_UCNV_H -DHAVE_MAGIC_H    -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ss                                          p-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fno-strict-aliasing  -fPIC  -Wall -funroll-loops   -c transliterator.cpp
common.h:14: warning: 'VALUE charlock_new_enc_str(const char*, size_t, void*)' defined but not used
common.h:32: warning: 'VALUE charlock_new_str2(const char*)' defined but not used
gcc -shared -o charlock_holmes.so encoding_detector.o converter.o ext.o transliterator.o -L. -L/usr/lib64 -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dy                                          namic -L/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes     -lruby -lmagic_ext -licui18n -licui18n  -lpthread                                           -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmagic_ext
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [charlock_holmes.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.8/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/gem_make.out
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

Error: /Stage[main]/Gitlab::Setup/Package[charlock_holmes]/ensure: change from absent to 0.6.9.4 failed: Could not update: Execution of                                           '/usr/bin/gem install -v 0.6.9.4 --no-rdoc --no-ri charlock_holmes' returned 1: ERROR:  Error installing charlock_holmes:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -licui18n... yes
checking for main() in -licui18n... yes
checking for unicode/ucnv.h... yes
  -- tar zxvf file-5.08.tar.gz
  -- ./configure --prefix=/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/dst/ --disable-shared --enable-stat                                          ic --with-pic
  -- patch -p0 < ../file-soft-check.patch
  -- make -C src install
  -- make -C magic install
checking for main() in -lmagic_ext... yes
checking for magic.h... yes
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
gcc -I.  -I/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/dst/include -I. -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux                                           -I. -DHAVE_UNICODE_UCNV_H -DHAVE_MAGIC_H    -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ss                                          p-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fno-strict-aliasing  -fPIC  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c encoding_detector.c
common.h:14: warning: 'charlock_new_enc_str' defined but not used
gcc -I.  -I/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/dst/include -I. -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux                                           -I. -DHAVE_UNICODE_UCNV_H -DHAVE_MAGIC_H    -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ss                                          p-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fno-strict-aliasing  -fPIC  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c converter.c
common.h:23: warning: 'charlock_new_str' defined but not used
common.h:32: warning: 'charlock_new_str2' defined but not used
gcc -I.  -I/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/dst/include -I. -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux                                           -I. -DHAVE_UNICODE_UCNV_H -DHAVE_MAGIC_H    -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ss                                          p-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fno-strict-aliasing  -fPIC  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c ext.c
common.h:14: warning: 'charlock_new_enc_str' defined but not used
common.h:23: warning: 'charlock_new_str' defined but not used
common.h:32: warning: 'charlock_new_str2' defined but not used
g++ -I.  -I/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/dst/include -I. -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux                                           -I. -DHAVE_UNICODE_UCNV_H -DHAVE_MAGIC_H    -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ss                                          p-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fno-strict-aliasing  -fPIC  -Wall -funroll-loops   -c transliterator.cpp
common.h:14: warning: 'VALUE charlock_new_enc_str(const char*, size_t, void*)' defined but not used
common.h:32: warning: 'VALUE charlock_new_str2(const char*)' defined but not used
gcc -shared -o charlock_holmes.so encoding_detector.o converter.o ext.o transliterator.o -L. -L/usr/lib64 -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dy                                          namic -L/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes     -lruby -lmagic_ext -licui18n -licui18n  -lpthread                                           -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmagic_ext
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [charlock_holmes.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.8/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/gem_make.out
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

Comment: What OS is this? Perhaps you are lacking a package libmagic-ext or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using a system ruby 1.8 which is pretty deprecated. Update to `>= 1.9.3` which is what GitLab requires. It is recommended to build it from source. If you install it through your package manager, make sure to also install the ruby devel package which is needed for gems with native extensions.